# Is the latest provided php5 package in an LTS distribution secure?

Tags: 12.04, security, php, lts

I need to update php5 on a 12.04 LTS production server. The latest candidate provided is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9. Is that version patched to be secure for use in a production environment?

PHP is up to 5.5.3 already and will prove quite a hassle to upgrade to. I would expect an LTS release to provide packages that will be patched with security fixes, but I cannot find a conclusive answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ) on the Ubuntu Wiki:

> Ubuntu is currently divided into four components: main, restricted, universe and multiverse. Packages in main and restricted are supported by the Ubuntu Security team for the life of an Ubuntu release, while packages in universe and multiverse are supported by the Ubuntu community.

PHP5.3 is part of the main component (as listed on the [php5 package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5)) and as such is supported by the Ubuntu security team until April 2017 ([12.04 LTS end of life date](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)).

As listed on the php5 package page, the latest security patch for php 5.3, at time of writing, is of March 3, 2014 ([5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10)).

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the release notes for versions past 5.3, there is no mention of security patches being issued with the releases. In every case, they do recommend testing code under the new versions because of deprecated functions in the newer releases.

To see if your existing code would be impacted, check [the 5.3 Release Notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php).

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking more for a statement with respect to LTS packages being officially maintained with security patches. Apparently they are if a package is part of main or restricted. I will add an answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Whiskey I'm relatively sure that I've seen PHP module updates coming down with the system updates, which makes it harder to track what is being kept current. Certainly we aren't running the current stable release, but I'm pretty confident that we are getting module patches.